# error when upload file to remote server (Windows, cURL)

Tags: php, windows, file, curl, upload

When I use linux this script working. But if I use Windows then script not working. Script:

```
$url="http://site.com/upload.php";
$post=array('image'=>'@'.getcwd().'\\images\\image.jpg');
$this->ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$body = curl_exec($this->ch);
echo $body;
```

Error in log:

*** failed creating formpost data**

File exists and readable.

Comment: Not an answer (nor the likely solution), but as an aside I would use [DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php) when referring to path names). (Or at the very least, stick with using forward slashes (`/`) as windows is indifferent, but *nix minds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is printed out when you do:

```
echo $post['image'];
```

Does it print out the correct file path?
Are you running this as CLI or an Apache installation on Windows?
You might have to use:

```
$post['image'] = '@'.dirname(__FILE__).'\\images\\image.jpg';
```